# .aspx page not showing ddl

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a webform that is working fine; Testpage.aspx, Testpage.aspx.cs and Testpage.aspx.designer.cs

Currently there is a text box.

```
<td style="width: 30%">
  <asp:TextBox ID="function" runat="server">
  </asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

I want to change it to dropdownlist.

```
<td style="width: 30%">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlfunction" runat="server">
  </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
```

I did this but the moment i made this change my entire html page is not loading and it just shows an empty white page. How do i troubleshoot this and where did i go wrong?

Comment: You troubleshoot by including your code with your question. Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Testpage.aspx.designer.cs` probably was not automatically updated correctly. The easiest thing to do would be to delete the DropDownList, compile (f5) , and then put it back again.